# Can I provide access to only a single or subset of videos for download from the API

Tags: oauth, vimeo, vimeo-api

the use case is that I'd like Vimeo users to supply me a vimeo link to a specific file (and the upload_ticket), and only have access to that one particular video and no other video in that user's account. How does one do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by Vimeo's API. If you have access to download one video, you have access to download all of their videos.